# :1: script.rb:91: , unexpected '\n' (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby

what does this error mean ??

i ran

```
script.rb apples
```

and i get

```
:1: script.rb:91: , unexpected '\n' (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 8):

Exactly what it says.  You've got a newline somewhere it's not allowed.  I can tell you exactly where it is if you include the source code in the vicinity of line 91.  5 lines of code on either side of line 91 should do it.